# php & apache multilingual web site /en/ /de/ /fr/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website in English and would like to have it translated to other languages. Reading other web resources I decided to have multilingual web site of the following format:

> www.mysite.com/en/index.php
>
> www.mysite.com/ru/index.php
>
> www.mysite.com/fr/index.php

etc.

I don't want to have my multilingual website based on sub domain

> www.en.mysite.com/index.php

or based on PHP $_GET

> www.mysite.com/index.php?lang=en

I have index.php file (in the directory www.mysite.com/index.php) with some other php included files to run the site. All the text of the web site is stored in the corresponding lang.php file (e.g. en.lang.php, ru.lang.php etc.). Inside each lang.php file there is an array for the corresponding language:

en.lang.php:

```
$arrLang = [
0 => "This is title tag description",
1 => "This is h1 header",
2 => "This is paragraph text",
]
```

ru.lang.php:

```
$arrLang = [
0 => "Это описание тега description",
1 => "Это заголовок h1",
2 => "Это текст параграфа",
]
```

My index.php file has the following content:

```
<?php
include_once 'en.lang.php';
echo "<html>";
echo "<header>";
echo "<title>$arrLang[0]</title>";
echo "</header>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<h1>$arrLang[1]</h1>";
echo "<p>$arrLang[2]</p>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

What do I need to do to have multilingual website of the desired link format:

> www.mysite.com/en/index.php
>
> or
>
> www.mysite.com/ru/index.php

Comment: For such a setup, I used gettext.  Since gettext replaces the text for you automatically, it is much simpler to debug your code later on.  Imagine in a couple months, your code will be filed with $arrLang[x] entries all over, without knowing what the text is.

Comment: You could set a cookie for the language and have the Include File change depending on what the cookie is.

Comment: For your question, you can check the URL your client used to get to index.php and define the language based on /en/ or /ru.  Check $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Comment: Seriously, do not try to roll your own multilingual support. This path leads only to madness and ruin. http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: @Nic3500 Ok, noted about gettext. It is clear about $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] check. But how do I convert from www.mysite.com/index.php to www.mysite.com/en/index.php Isn't it related to Apache setup?

Comment: may be url rewriting can help